# Perf Counter "Internet Information Services Global" not available in Azure Web Role?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

We have a requirement to monitor azure webrole. One of the requirement is to monitor below:

```
\Internet Information Services Global\Current Files Cached
```

However this is not coming through WADPerformanceMonitorTable.

Could someone confirm if this is or not available in Azure web Role

Comment: You can simply RDP into an instance and look at Perfmon

Comment: It's not there , should it be and why it's not there (bug?)

Answer (score 0):

upon further checking, Internet Information Services Global performance counter category is available for IIS6 on Windows 2003 family of servers:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784792(v=ws.10).aspx

Check out *ASP.NET Applications* and *ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319* categories perhaps?